# Count number of individual lines from a txt file c#

Tags: c#, duplicates, line-count

I have a txt document which has over 14000 different lines many of these are duplicates, is it possible to count the number of unique entries?

Comment: Please make sure to verify which version of .NET you are using in the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simply "One-Liner" like that:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("FileToRead.txt").Distinct().Count();
```

**Edit:**
But take care with those kind of solutions. With files larger than 600 MB you might get problems.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [File.ReadLines Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) and LINQ's [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) and [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count.aspx) [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
var result = File.ReadLines("input.txt").Distinct().Count();
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterate through the file, save what you find in a collection, ignore already analyzed entries and in the end, just check the size of the collection.